# Why Out of Stock Products showing at end of list in Magento 2.4.5?

Tags: product-list, sorting, out-of-stock, product-sorting, magento2.4.5p1

We have created a category page and assigned some products to that category page.

We have also assigned some out-of-stock products.

But when we sort products by price the out-of-stock products show at end of the list.

How can we show the out-of-stock product in the proper position based on the sort order?

[image]

Comment: The same issue I am facing, if you get answer please let me know ?

Comment: @Dotsquares Yes, I have found the issue, Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this issue, There is a default **is_salable** sort order added in elasticsearch that's why out-of-stock products showing at end of the listing.

You can able to remove that sort order by overriding the below file and removing line #213.

> vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/SearchResultApplier.php

On line #213 the below code was added in elasticsearch

```
$sortOrders = array_merge(['is_salable' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_DESC], $sortOrders);
```

[image]